# Test if name resolv with ping (or better than that)

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, ping, stderr

I have a bash function:

```
resolv(){
  for name in $*; do
    test 1 -eq $(ping -c 1 -q "$name"|grep '1 packet transmitted'|wc -l) && echo ok || echo fail
  done
}
```

But if I pass a name that is not defined it returns, always:

```
ping: unknown host name.that.do.not.resolv
fail
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: do you mean to do the same as `host`?

Comment: yes, but `host` not run for names defineds into /etc/hosts

Comment: side note - a host not responding to ping will also fail, which might not be what you want

Answer (score 1):

You could try `getent` which follows the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` config:

```
> getent hosts my_laptop
127.0.0.1       localhost my_laptop
> getent hosts www.google.com
2607:f8b0:400b:80a::1014 www.google.com
> getent hosts name.that.do.not.resolv
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the assumption you need to use ping (because, for example, of the broken^H^H^Hconfused dns resolution in OSX):

Note that your grep wasn't portable - some pings say "packet" and others say "packets"...   within the scope of the ping's I had available, ^PING works though.

For your specific question, you wanted to suppress the error output - so just redirect stderr to /dev/null - if it's sh/bash/similar that'd just be `2>/dev/null`

Also added -t1 to reduce the amount of time we might spend on a ping fail/lookup fail...might need to tune to suit.

Broke up the `test && ||` into something more readable (and with more obvious logic direction) since we arent really constrained to a oneliner. :)

```
#!/bin/sh

resolv(){
  for name in $*; do

    count=$(ping -c 1 -q -t1 "$name" 2>/dev/null |grep '^PING'|wc -l)
    if  [ 1 -eq "$count" ]
     then
        echo ok
    else
        echo fail
    fi
  done
}

resolv google.com
resolv icantclick.org
resolv www.yahoo.com
resolv gofish
```